# single sided buffer in pyqgis 3 gives "_core.QgsProcessingException: Error calculating single sided buffer" error

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am trying to create a single sided buffer around drains (polygon shapefile). The Distance parameter must be taken from a field in drains shp. Here is my code:

```
buf_out = self.dlg.lineEdit_3.text()    
b1 = drainLayer.fields().indexFromName('b1')    
processing.run('qgis:singlesidedbuffer',{'INPUT': drainLayer, 'DISTANCE': b1,'SIDE':1, 'SEGMENTS':25, 'JOIN_STYLE':0, 'OUTPUT':buf_out})
```

I tried giving an int value for distance but even that didnt work. An empty shapefile is created and qgis processing exception is raised. Normal buffer is working but one sided buffer is not working.

Comment: I believe single sided buffer only works with line inputs

Comment: yes thats right .. it works only for line inputs.. thank you.. just now found out.